# Bottom Bar Navigation in Nativescript not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

I am using https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-bottom-navigation#bottom-navigation-bar for implementing bottom navigation bar using Angular. I tried the steps they were providing but unfortunately it's not working. I am getting an error like `can't find variable MDCBottomNavigationBarDelegate`. 
I am stuck here and I really doubt whether Nativescript is a good framework over other popular ones. If anyone here know about this issue, please help.

Or is there any good solutions to implement bottom navigation for Android and IOS?

This is something I want to achieve
[image]

Comment: That sounds like the dependencies were not installed. Make sure you run a clean build. In case if you are using Preview App, use `tns run`

Comment: Any update on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use build in TabView of native script. By using     `androidTabsPosition="bottom"` you can set the position for it

```
<TabView
  androidTabsPosition="bottom"
  androidSelectedTabHighlightColor="#7c015d"
  selectedTabTextColor="#7c015d"
>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Today' }">
    <router-outlet name="today"> </router-outlet>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Current Challenge' }">
    <router-outlet name="currentChallenge"> </router-outlet>
  </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

And in your component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

  constructor(
    private router: RouterExtensions,
    private active: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(
      [
        {
          outlets: { currentChallenge: ["current-challenge"], today: ["today"] }
        }
      ],
      { relativeTo: this.active }
    );
  }
```

Update you can do like this to set icon

```
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Title', iconSource:'res://icon'}">
```

Comment: But here how we add icons

Comment: You can add icons in TabView too.